# mysql recreating dropped table after 24 hours

Tags: mysql, myisam

i have a script that create tables by current date.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
 INDEX sbcname (sbcname),
 INDEX starttime (starttime),
 PRIMARY KEY(myid),
 UNIQUE KEY(callid),
 myid bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 starttime varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 blah, blah, blah,
 routeHeader varchar(128)
) ENGINE= MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;"

exit 0;

=> table bsasu_20170805 created.
```

After a long time period, i need to remove some tables using `drop table bsasu_20170805;`

The `bsasu_20170805` table is dropped, also both files `bsasu_20170805.frm`, `bsasu_20170805.MYD` and `bsasu_20170805.MYI` are remove from mysql data path.

Its ok as expected. But, 24 hours late all tables are recreating by itself and i don't know the reason and not how to troubleshooting it.

Any clue?

Best regards,

Luis Veiga

Comment: The simplest explanation is that it's your script, and it's creating the table with the wrong table name.

Comment: Is the machine hosted by some service that is too aggressive about not losing anything?

Comment: Hello Bill, you are absolutely right!
my script have a 'comment' disabling some delete command.
You fix my problem. Thanx a lot !